Simplicity of Jacobian of curves of genus 2
Let $p\neq 2$ and $a, b, \in \overline {\mathbb F_{p}}\setminus \{0,1\}$ two elements distinct from each other, and let $s$ be an element which is transcendental over $\overline {\mathbb F_{p}}$.
We put $C$ a hyperelliptic curve over $\overline {\mathbb F_{p}(s)}$ defined by $y^{2}=x(x-1)(x-a)(x-b)(x-s)$ and $J_{C}$ the Jacobian of $C$.
(a): $J_{C}$ is a simple abelian variety.
(b): $J_{C}$ is isogenous to a product of copies of generic elliptic curves (i.e. the curve corresponding to a geometric point over the generic point of the moduli space $M_{1,1}$).
My questions are as follows:
Can we know when $J_{C}$ satisfies conditions (a) or (b) above?
If we put $S:=\{C \ | \ \text{neither (a) nor (b) is satisfied} \}$, is $S$ a finite set?

Is $t=s$ in the equation of $C$? Also what is a generic elliptic curve?

@Jef,  Thank you. I revised the content.
